# Vuetify: DataTable with Array of Strings

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

This seems like another simple question, but is there a possibility to create a Vuetify DataTable with an Array of Strings?
I don't wanna use a simple DataTable, because I need the selection.
I might do some "v-for" and create custom objects, but isn't there a solution implemented by Vuetify?

In my Vue-Components I've got following HTML:

```
<v-data-table
     show-select
     single-select
     :items="myItems"
     v-model="mySelectedItems"/>
```

The myItems Property is an Array containing only Strings (Not objects).

When I open my page the console shows me following error:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "item". Expected Object, got String with value "Value1"

Edit:
Example data:

```
...
data() {
    return {
        myItems: ["Value1", "Value2"]
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of your data with an array of strings?

Comment: Edited the question with the example

Comment: Looks like it requires an array of objects. Then, simply transform your array of strings into an array of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is probably because Vuetify's `v-data-table` component expects to receive an array of objects, while you are only providing an array of string. You can simply convert your array of string into a dummy array of objects using `Array.prototype.map`, and bind the computed property instead.

The transformation is pretty simple:

```
this.myItems.map(function(item) {
  return {
    item: item
  }
});
```

If you're familiar with ES6, this can be further shortened into a one-liner:

```
this.myItems.map(item => ({ item }));
```

Also, you will need to provide `v-data-table` with a `headers` attribute, so that it knows what key in the object should be matched to which column.

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: function() {
    return {
      myItems: ["Value1", "Value2"],
      headers: [{
        text: 'Column',
        value: 'item' // Must match the key used in `myItemsTransformed`
      }]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    myItemsTransformed() {
      return this.myItems.map(item => ({ item }));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-data-table
    show-select
    single-select
    :items="myItemsTransformed"
    :headers="headers" />
</div>
```

Comment: That's a lot of workaround for such a simple data-table. I will include your answer into my code and see if anyone else provides a more simply solution. Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: Dont know why my Question was downvoted, but it seems there is no other solution. It works in my project, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Febertson I don't know why do you mean by "a lot of workaround": it's essentially remapping a simple array to an array of objects, and feeding that transformed array to the table.